# Algorithm for calculating sum of powers, $(\sum_{i=1}^n i^k ) \bmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Supposse $p$ as a prime number.
Is it possible to calculate $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^k\right) \bmod p$ faster than
$O(n\log{k})$ or $O(k\log{n}\log{k})$?

For $O(n\log{k})$, repeated squaring for each term achive this.
For $O(k\log{n}\log{k})$, defining $f_k(m):=\sum_{i=1}^m i^k$,  $f_k(m+1)=1+\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}f_j(m)$ holds. So, using fast polynomial remainder algorithm, this is possible.

More fast computing possible?

Update(17:58, 05/10/2019)

$O(\sqrt{kn}\log({kn}))$ is possible accroding to [this](https://min-25.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/03/224429).

Update(16:31, 07/10/2019)

Accroding to latte0199-san, $O(k\log{k})$ is possible. Enumerating Bernoulli number up to kth can be done in $O(k\log k)$ by expanding generating function with formal power series. From Faulhaber's formula, sum of powers can be expressed by convolution of Bernuilli number. By using FFT, convolution can be done in $O(k\log{k})$.

Since $\min(k,n)\geq\sqrt{kn}$, the algorithm of $O(n\log k)$ or $O(k\log k)$ is always better compared to $O(\sqrt{kn} \log(nk))$.

Comment: for which value of $k$? ...

Comment: I suppose $k$ as an integer in the range of $1 \leq k \leq p-1$.

Comment: okay but with $k=p-1$ you check $n \bmod p$ and get your answer.

Comment: Yes. For special case such that $k$ is close to $0$ or $p-1$, we can calculate it fast. Especially when $k=p-1$, $i^k = 1$ and things are simple. But I don't know what to do for the middle.

Comment: find a generator like $3 \bmod 7$ then rephrase the sum in terms of that.

Comment: What's the meaning of generator? Primitive root modulo p?

Comment: it produces every residue mod that number.